# How to vertically center the text without using display: table-cell?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the menu appear at the middle of 30px line but the problem is that I cannot move it from the top unless I use display: table-cell.

What is wrong here?

Style sheet file:

```
div.menu
{
    width: 600; 
    height: 30px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: bottom
}
```

The menu code in my html file:

```
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-height: 100px;` set the height of your menu line. But keep enough space in horizontal dimension, otherwize you will get crazy view. Look forward to `min-width`, `width` or `overflow-x` rules.

```
div.menu
{
    width: 600px; 
    /* Use line-height instead of height */
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div.menu a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue but is not the correct way to do. You need to use `vertical-align` property for the anchors inside the `menu` division.

Answer (score 2):

setting the `line-height` to the desired value fixes the issue but it is not a correct way to do it. It is just a hack. The correct way is to use **`vertical-align`** property (for all the anchors inside the `menu` div)

```
.menu a {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but for the wrong element. `vertical-align` is used for `inline` elements. But you have used it for a `div` which is a `block-level` element.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sfz7d/

Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use this. I'm a bit rusty in HTML/CSS, haven't done it for over 2 years.